# how to know if a function has been run in python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, tkinter-button

I have code that has a tkinter ( GUI ) button in it. when you press the button , for example , the press() function that I declared with a def block runs. i want to know how to check if a function has been run and use it in a if block.
example:

```
def press()
    print("hello world")
press()

while True() :
    if press() has been runned (?) :
        print("printed")
```

can you help me with this? thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I'm pretty sure you trying something really unnecessary here and a simple *flag* will do the job.

Comment: nothing unnecessary , no . but what is a flag?

Comment: in tkinter you need to use the `.after()` method if you want to continuously check whether a function has been called with some specified frequency - using a while loop will cause your interface to freeze

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `tkinter.mainloop()`?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very basic solution by using a *flag*

```py
press_been_run = False

def press():
    print("hello world")
    global press_been_run 
    press_been_run = True

press()

if press_been_run:
    print("printed")
```

Comment: wait. it's so basic , why i did not think of this? but maybe it will not answer in my code. let me try :)

Comment: While I do agree with the method you are using, the fact the OP wants to run this in the context of a GUI eventloop makes the `while True` loop quite dangerous.